# How do UIApplicationMain code to lead memory leak?

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks, instruments

It shows in this line,it leaks 2Bytes.

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

And it always alert me that in main function there is memory leaks
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the same leak using Instruments and Xcode 6.4.